# Why does my navbar have a margin on the sides in mobile view in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, margin, navbar

Ok so here is all my code just a simple navbar with some css styling and for some reason every time I shrink it to mobile view it doesn't go 100% of the screens width and has a margin to the right and left of it of about 20px

#### CSS

```
.navbar .brand {
    width:150px;;
}
 .nav-collapse > ul >li{
    padding-top:50px;
 }
 html, body {
     margin:0px;!important
     padding:0px;!important
     }

.nav .active a { background:#06F!important;
color:white!important;
}



    /* CUSTOMIZE THE NAVBAR
    -------------------------------------------------- */
    .navbar-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      z-index: 10;
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-bottom: -90px; 
    }
    .navbar-wrapper .navbar {


    }

    /* Remove border and change up box shadow for more contrast */
    .navbar .navbar-inner {
      border: 0;
    }

    /* Downsize the brand/project name a bit */
    .navbar .brand {
      padding: 14px 20px 16px; /* Increase vertical padding to match navbar links */
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
      width:150px;
    }

    /* Navbar links: increase padding for taller navbar */
    .navbar .nav > li > a {
      padding: 18px 20px;
    }

    /* Offset the responsive button for proper vertical alignment */
    .navbar .btn-navbar {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }



    /* RESPONSIVE CSS
    -------------------------------------------------- */

    @media (max-width: 979px) {

      .container.navbar-wrapper {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        width: auto;
      }
      .navbar-inner {

        margin: 0px 0px -20px 0;
      }


    }


    @media (max-width: 767px) {

        .navbar {
            width:100%;
            }
        .navbar .navbar-inner {
        width:100%;
        margin-right:0px;
            margin-left:0px;

            }

      .navbar-inner {
        margin: 0px 0px -20px 0;
      }

    }
```

#### HTML

```
 <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-inner btn-block">
        <div class="container">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="brand" href="#">MOBILE</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse text-center">
            <ul class="nav pull-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--container END-->
      </div>
    </div>
```

#### SCRIPT

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
    <script src="docs/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="docs/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="docs/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="docs/assets/js/holder/holder.js"></script>
    <script src="docs/assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/application.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap CSS adds padding to body on small screens:

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
  body {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
}
```

Try overwriting with:

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
  body {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test your code with the scripts, but you can try this;

```
.navbar-wrapper, .navbar, .navbar-inner, .container{
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:0;
  padding-left:0;
  padding-right:0;
}
```

at the top of your css. The other css (creating margin and padding) will overrule after this if you put it at the top.

If it does not work, try putting this at the bottom, to see if it works in any way. If it does at the bottom of your css, the problem is in your code. If not, the problem could be in the scripts made by bootstrap giving it style tags, that always overrule external css.

Comment: That didn't work I guess it's just bootstraps CSS that needs overwriting. Thanks for the heads up.